# Get id from multiple checkbox when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get current id on click.and checked only one checkbox. Here are my input boxes

```
<table style="width: 500px; border: 1px solid BLACK;">
  <?php for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){ ?>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id="chkBox<?php echo  $i; ?>" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="myTagCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id="chkBox<?php echo $i; ?>"  value=""/></td>
  <td><?php echo $i;?></td></tr> 
  <?php }?>
</table>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function(e){
     $('input#chkBox1').on('change', function() {
        $('input#chkBox1').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });
  });
```

its work for first one. I didn't get the other id on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('input').on('click', function(e){
    var id = e.target.id;
    $('input#'+id).on('change', function() {
        $('input#'+id).not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });

  });
});
```

FIDDLE HERE
http://jsfiddle.net/spydo9s3/

Answer (score 0):

The code you have there is targeting one checkbox (ID: chkBox1). Your PHP is ID'ing them dynamically, so chkBox1, chkBox2 etc.

Perhaps what you want is a more dynamic click listener, such as:

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
    $('input.chkTag').on('change', function()
    {
        $('input.chkTag').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

This would target the class that each input shares instead.

Comment: I want checked one from two checkbox in a row. my php dynamically increased row.and i want to checked one checkbox in each row

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: Oh, do you want it so that only 1 checkbox per row can be selected?

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique! You must change in your PHP so that each input gets a unique ID not same as any else.

Something like:

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){ ?>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id="chkBox_0_<?php echo  $i; ?>" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="myTagCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id="chkBox_1_<?php echo $i; ?>"  value=""/></td>
  <td><?php echo $i;?></td></tr> 
<?php }?>
```

And in the jQuery you need not more than:

```
$('input.chkTag').on('change', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    // do something with id
});
```

If you just want one of them checked at time then you need not `type="checkbox"` but `type="radio"`